# Setting up a camera to make the world look large

Tags: rendering, camera, unreal

I am attempting to configure my camera to give the impression of a normal sized player in a giant room. Since units are arbitrary, I figured this should be possible (despite the fact that the room is technically 24x24m big and I want it to feel more like a hangar).

I have tried tweaking down the FOV (to about 40 degrees) which has helped some, but I can't shake the feeling that I am a tiny person in a normal sized room rather than a normal sized person in a giant room.

What about the way the scene is being rendered is giving away this to my eye. Or is it just a lack of reference points?

I am using Unreal Engine if that affects the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add details to show the scale of the world. In terms of rendering, there's no difference between a tiny person in a normal room and a normal person in a large room. If there's any fog, you should decrease the distance for it so as to make the space look larger.

It could also be the height of the ceiling in the room relative to the player height, which is going to be one of the main references people use to figure out the size of the player/room.

If you're making a hangar, add planes/helicopters/service vehicles at the correct scale relative to the player and the scale of the world should feel correct.

Also a side note, I'm not sure about the Unreal engine, but most physics engines don't like it when you scale the world size up or down a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, the technical stuff that probably goes without saying, but...

- Camera very low to ground (TPPOV (Tiny Player Point Of View))
- Player movement speed scaled down

Second, the art stuff, that probably is what you're missing.  This translates into...

- Brand new textures are required that show in fact what something looks like very close up.  It has to be REALLY super fine detail.  All the little lumps in the linoleum, fine wood grain, tiny details in a potted plant's leaf, etc.
- Brand new little details like dust bunnies, small items on floor that you normally don't see (paper clip, finger nail clipping, dead bug, dropped pencil, etc.)

Go lay on the floor in a room and look at what you can see close up.  Do it with a magnifying glass.  It's all that little stuff that's going to make a huge difference.

Comment: By TPPOV, do you mean the field of view angle should be very small or is there omse other aspect you are referring to?

Comment: I would say the FOV is the same.  A tiny person still has the same FOV as a tall person, no?